# Multi-Tenant Django application using SQL Server as database

Tags: sql-server, django, celery, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create a multi-tenant Django application using SQL Server, which should support per-tenant db isolation. For PostgreSQL there are packages like django-multitenant and django-tenant-schemas. But I cannot find any library for the same using SQL Server db. What's the best approach to solving this problem? Any help on this is much appreciated.
Requirement:

1. Database SQL Server (must).
2. Tenant and Db creation on the fly.
3. db routing.
4. Celery support for the same.
5. Applying Migration for all the databases.

Comment: because the concept is not natove for sql server, a instance can have mulitple identical databases(schema) per user, but it is usually discouraged

Comment: From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwqme.png

Comment: Multiple identical database is not possible. I just tried to create a database with the name db1 2 times but on the 2nd time, I got the error saying db1 already exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official documentation which supports mssql server for multi-tenants. Use django's muti-database management system & it may be offers you a solution.